# Custom tasks in kogito vscode bpmn editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, kogito

Is it possible to show custom tasks from a wid file in the palette of tasks in the VSCode BPMN2 editor? If not, is there another way to add custom tasks to a business process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible, but there are some limitations. See [this article](https://blog.kie.org/2021/05/simplest-custom-tasks-in-kogito.html).

Please, pay attention that only one VS Code project can be opened at a time and other restrictions mentioned in the article.

Also, you may be interested to check alternatives to WID task, see pros and cons for different custom logic types [in this article](https://blog.kie.org/2021/06/custom-logic-in-bpmn.html).

Comment: Keeping only one project in the workspace solved the issue. I can open additional VSCode windows if I need to open more than one project at a time.

Comment: Both articles were very helpful. Thank you!